# I'm stuck with this "Make this anonymous inner class a lambda"

Tags: java, sonarcloud

```
builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return hostname!=null;
    }
});
```

I need help to refactor this code. I don't know from where to start. I've tried everything, but I find lambda expressions complicated.

Comment: I was able to solve this ... could you please tell me if it's correct : 

 builder.hostnameVerifier((h,s) -> h!=null);

Comment: This is correct. You should post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Please do post and accept your answer to your own question. And add a bit of explanation for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 1):

```
HostnameVerifier hv =(String urlHostName, SSLSession session)-> {
    return hostname!=null;
};
```